# How to derive the solution to the optimization problem

Tags: matrices, optimization

$\max_{\mathbf{h}} \frac{1}{k} (  \frac{1}{\mathbf{h}^H \mathbf{\Gamma_0} \mathbf{h}} + \frac{1}{\mathbf{h}^H\mathbf{\Gamma_1} \mathbf{h}} +....+\frac{1}{\mathbf{h}^H\mathbf{\Gamma_{k-1}} \mathbf{h}}) \ \ s.t \ \ \mathbf{h}^H\mathbf{D}_0 = \mathbf{1}^T$, where $\mathbf{h}$ is a vector of length $M$, $\mathbf{\Gamma}_k$ are what we've known as Hermitian matrixes of size $M\times M$, $\mathbf{D}_0$ corresponds to the $k$ constraints with size $M\times k$. $^H$ is the complex conjugate transpose and $^T$ is the transpose operator.

How to solve the problem?